# Can I integrate Ambari after installing Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, ambari

I've a 3 node Apache Nifi cluster and now I would like to put monitoring on top of it. Apache Ambari will be a good monitoring tool for it. Will I be able to integrate Ambari with Nifi?  Or I need to  installed Ambari first and then use Ambari feature to install Nifi. Note : I'm using open source software and not HortonWork.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, I don't think it is possible to add an existing NiFi cluster as a new service to Ambari. You need to have Ambari then create and install the NiFi service.

Once installed, to monitor your NiFi service, you can use `AmbariReportingTask` available in NiFi to report statistics to your Ambari server for monitoring.

**Useful Links**

- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-ambari-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.reporting.ambari.AmbariReportingTask/index.html
- https://pierrevillard.com/2017/05/16/monitoring-nifi-ambari-grafana/